# Force Regenerate Thumbnails Broke My images

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have moved to a new theme then used Force Regenerate Thumbnails to regenerate post images, but after 24 hours of FRT working, I found a lot of images are missing [from my posts](https://www.arch2o.com/kapor-center-social-impact-fougeron-architecture/). Maybe because my website relies on different sizes of the image.

Using chrome debug, I can see such an error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
So, I tried to add `the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );` function to my theme but it didn't work. 
Is there any other function that could REforce WordPress to regenerate thumbnails or call the medium image size to replace the inserted ones?

Answer (score 0):

We've had great luck using the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin. It may take a minute to run based on how many posts and image sizes you have, but I don't know that I've seen it fail and we've used it on.

However it also seems like some of your source images are missing:

[Missing](http://www.arch2o.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Arch2O-Kapor-Center-Fougeron-Architecture.jpg) - [Not Missing](http://www.arch2o.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Arch2O-Kapor-Center-Fougeron-Architecture-01.jpg)

I'd rectify any missing source images first before running the plugin.

Comment: I run Regenerate Thumbnails but with no much luck, is there any way I can recall all themes using function?